# Django query disappearing in postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I have set up a few models in a simple django project.  When I run

```
python manage.py sql fivefives
```

I get loads of nice looking sql, when I run syncdb or validate I get 0 errors.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "fivefives_player" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "username" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "colour" varchar(7) NOT NULL,
    "remaining_dice" integer NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "fivefives_game_player_list" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "game_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "player_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "fivefives_player" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("game_id", "player_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "fivefives_game" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE "fivefives_game_player_list" ADD CONSTRAINT "game_id_refs_id_c39af54" FOREIGN KEY ("game_id") REFERENCES "fivefives_game" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "fivefives_round_player_list" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "round_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "player_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "fivefives_player" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("round_id", "player_id")
)
; ... it continues like this...
```

But as soon as I hop into admin the tables aren't there. Logging into postgres I see the tables haven't even been created.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'perudodb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Anyone come up with anything like this before? Just copied all files onto my friends computer and syncdb'd and it all works great.

Comment: Urghhh moment. The 'postgres' default user I was using clearly was lacking something. I just changed to dave, my mac's superuser, ran syncdb and it all happened and is now working.

Comment: The answer was already posted. But one hint: use south. It handles schema migrations and is the de-facto standard.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out - needed exactly this to make a field null=True after I'd already created it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually create the tables, you want `manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 0):

`manage.py sql` doesn't actually run the SQL, it just prints it.